# Change the size of button present on Add-ins Custom Toolbar (VBA Code, Excel)

Tags: excel, vba

I have created buttons with the help of VBA Code on Add-ins. How can I make the button size larger (change the size)? I have tried methods like height and width but they did not help me.

part of the code:

```
Sub Auto_Open()
    x = x + 1
    Set oControl = oBar.Controls.Add(ID:=specifyID, Before:=x)
    oControl.OnAction = "Specify Action" 
    oControl.FaceId = SpecifyFaceID
    oControl.Caption = "Specify Caption" '(Not provided any values)
End Sub
```

`oControl` is `CommandBarControl`

I have tried `oControl.Height` and `oControl.Width` but it did not help.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible from VBA. it may be possible using RibbonXml fluent design, but it's been some time since I did that (some controls are sizeable within allowed sizes like small, medium or large, not sure if applicable to buttons). But that is a very different and more complicated question/implementation.

Comment: [*The use of CommandBars in some Microsoft Office applications has been superseded by the new ribbon component of the Microsoft Office Fluent user interface.*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.commandbarbutton.height)